# How can I display a formatted date from a Unix timestamp in twig?

Tags: php, symfony, filter, twig, unix-timestamp

I would like to display a formatted date in twig by applying a filter to a Unix timestamp. Is such a feature available in twig?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is a filter called [**`date`**](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html).

In the following example `mydate` equals `1286199900`:

```
{{ mydate|date }}           <!-- October 4, 2010 13:45 -->
{{ mydate|date('d/m/Y') }}  <!-- 04/10/2010 -->
```

Comment: Yes, I figured out that actually the date filter does handle Unix timestamps only I was providing the 13-digit timestamp instead of the 10-digit one and that confused the filter. I don't suppose there is a simple way of handling 13-digit timestamps with the date filter, isn't there?

Comment: Maybe `{% set newdate = mydate / 1000 %}{{ newdate|date }}`

Comment: That never even crossed my mind. Thank you, it worked like a charm.

Comment: This doesn't work in Jtwig (Java). It throws an exception. Expects a Date object or "now" strinig.

Comment: Wonder if the date filter will automatically translate in the right langage ?

Answer (score 6):

If you just divide it by 1000 there might be an error like
`Failed to parse time string (1384361503.5) at position 7`

I would add round function to it

`{% set timestamp = (rating.ratingDate / 1000)|round(0, 'floor') %}
{{timestamp|date('d. M Y')}}`

I know I am playing an archaeologist but it might be helpful for someone.

Comment: that did help !