# convert this timestamp value into date format

Tags: twig

Joining Date : `975628800`

```
{{ timestamp|format_date('field_joining_date') }}
```

How to convert this timestamp format to date format?

Comment: {{ field_joining_date.value|date("d/m/Y") }}  I have tried this but it is showing current date not the actual result

Comment: Please paste the code as text into your question then highlight and press Ctrl+K this allows us to copy and paste your code into our IDEs and help identify the problem. Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to know what code you need to include

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display a formatted date from a Unix timestamp in twig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003673/how-can-i-display-a-formatted-date-from-a-unix-timestamp-in-twig)